# How to install packages on EMR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I created a cluster on AWS and with Jupyter, python3 installed. Now I can type code in the cells and I found 'numpy' is installed, i.e., by `import numpy as np`, I am able to access the functions in this package. However, I found `pandas` is not there. So in the next cell I typed `!pip install pandas`, then it displays

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /mnt/usrmoved/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /mnt/usrmoved/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.0 in /mnt/usrmoved/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /mnt/usrmoved/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /mnt/usrmoved/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->pandas)
```

I thought it is successfully installed, but then in the next cell, I type `import pandas as pd` it gives me an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               
Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-8-af55e7023913> in <module>()----> 1 import pandas as pd

ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

In general, how should we install related python packages in EMR?

In my laptop, in the jupyter, I always did "! pip install package" and it works. But why it does not work in jupyer on EMR?

Comment: It's already installed at `mnt/usrmoved/local/lib64/python2.7`. If Jupyter isn't the using that Python executable, that's the problem

Comment: @cricket_007 can you elaborate that a little bit? Is there a way to fix that problem? The numpy works, it's weird. Is that because It is installed as python 2 but I use kernal as python 3?

Comment: I suggest that you run `which python` from an SSH session. Probably it's `/usr/bin/python`, which is the system installed python (which could have numpy, sure). In other words, you can have many installations of Python on a machine, and that doesn't mean that all packages are shared

Comment: @cricket_007 I opened the "terminal" from the Jupyter (is that the SSH session you mentioned) and typed "which python", it indeed generates `/usr/bin/python` as you said. I solve this problem by switch the kernal to python 2. So which version of the python (as well as its packages) on AWS is not in our control right?

Comment: SSH or terminal, sure... The kernel is the important thing. If you have access to make different kernels, you can control what's installed where

Comment: Note that `which python` in the terminal doesn't necessarily mean that is the Python that the kernel is running

Answer (score 4):

I tried installing python packages using `pip install`, but I get the `pip: command not found`. So I used `pip3` instead of pip, and it worked.

Using EMR 5.30.1

Comment: `sudo: pip3: command not found` :(

Answer (score 1):

The conventional method to install python packages on EMR is to specify the packages needed at cluster creation using a bootstrap-action.

This method ensures the packages are installed on all nodes and not just the driver.

```
aws emr create-cluster \
--name 'test python packages' \
--release-label emr-5.20.0 \
--region us-east-1 \
--use-default-roles
--instance-type m4.large \
--instance-count 2 \
--bootstrap-actions \
    Path="s3://your-bucket/python-modules.sh",Name='Install Python Modules' \
```

The `python-modules.sh` would contain commands to install the python packages. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Install needed packages
sudo pip install pandas
```

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub-install-kernels-libs.html)

Comment: i am getting the error as:  sudo: pip: command not found

Comment: i customised my script to easy_install pip and then install pandas but got this error sudo: easy_install-3.4: command not found
sudo: /usr/local/bin/pip3: command not found